# ChartJS - Customize Ticks/Labels on Y Axis

Tags: chart.js

I have some sets of data that will only have 5 options, but they are not evenly distributed. For example, one set will be [1600, 1650, 1700, 1800, 1850]. I can't figure out how to get the axis to either hide "1750" or customize my own labels. Not even sure if those are the "labels" or "ticks".

Answer (score 0):

You can override the callback in the ticks setting to determine what label is displayed, for example:

```
ticks: {
  callback: function (value, index, values) {
    return (value % 2 === 0) ? value : "";
},
```

Will only display the labels for the even values and hide the rest. You can customise this function to do whatever you want, including adding symbols to the labels.